# adapter not set in the listview android

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am working on the list view, I just want to set the values in the listview. I posted the code as below.As per SimpleAdapter It just shows the name of the content .I want to display the count also.But the count does not displayed and in the app it only shows name of the textview instead of the count. Please suggest me solution for the problem.I also attached the screenshot.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.R.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Folders extends navigation_drawer_class {

    static final String NEW = "new", OVERDUE = "overdue", ASSIGNED = "assigned", TRASH = "trash", SPAM = "spam", NAME = "name", COUNT = "count";

    ListView folders_list;
    String[] folders;
    String[] filter_id = {
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
    };
    List < String > folder_count;
    JSONArray quick_view_array;
    JSONObject quick_view_obj, count_obj;
    String new_count, overdue_count, assigned_count, trash_count, spam_count;
    List < HashMap < String, String >> menuItems;
    Dialog dialog;
    String URL;
    Operation op = new Operation();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.folders);
        new getbrand().execute();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        //-----------------------
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.folders, frameLayout);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);
        //------------------------

        if (Operation.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            folders_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.folder_display_list);
            new folders().execute();

            folders_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

                    String fid = filter_id[position];
                    String title = folders[position];
                    Intent i = new Intent(Folders.this, Tickets.class);
                    i.putExtra("filter_id", "&vis_filter_id=" + fid);
                    i.putExtra("title", title);
                    i.putExtra("set_queue", "no");

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_network);
        }
    }
    private class folders extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, JSONArray > {
        Dialog dialog;
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new Dialog(Folders.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL = op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(), "ticket", "quick_view", "");
            quick_view_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL + "&vis_encode=json", Folders.this);
            return quick_view_array;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONArray quick_view_array) {
            super.onPostExecute(quick_view_array);
            try {
                quick_view_obj = quick_view_array.getJSONObject(0);
                count_obj = quick_view_obj.getJSONObject("count");
                folder_count = new ArrayList < String > ();
                folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(NEW));
                folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(OVERDUE));
                folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(ASSIGNED));
                folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(TRASH));
                folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(SPAM));
                folders = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.folders);
                menuItems = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> ();

                for (int i = 0; i < filter_id.length; i++) {
                    HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
                    map.put(NAME, folders[i]);
                    map.put(COUNT, folder_count.get(i));
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }

                SimpleAdapter list = new SimpleAdapter(Folders.this,
                    menuItems,
                    R.layout.folders,
                    new String[] {
                        NAME,
                        COUNT
                    },
                    new int[] {
                        R.id.folder_name, R.id.folder_count
                    }

                );
                folders_list.setAdapter(list);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        String filter_id = null, Tickets_title = null;
        int start_limit = 0, page_no = 1;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_inbox:
                Intent inbox = new Intent(Folders.this, Tickets.class);
                inbox.putExtra("filter_id", "&vis_filter_id=1");
                inbox.putExtra("title", "Inbox");
                inbox.putExtra("set_queue", "no");
                startActivity(inbox);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_new_ticket:
                Intent new_ticket = new Intent(Folders.this, New_Ticket_step1.class);
                startActivity(new_ticket);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_ticket_queue:
                Intent ticket_queue = new Intent(Folders.this, Queues.class);
                ticket_queue.putExtra("set_queue", "set");
                startActivity(ticket_queue);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_clients:
                Intent clients = new Intent(Folders.this, Client.class);
                startActivity(clients);
                return true;

                /* case R.id.menu_blabby:
                Intent blabby = new Intent(Folders.this,Blabby.class);
                blabby.putExtra("operation","get_blabs");
                blabby.putExtra("filter","");
                blabby.putExtra("title",(String)getString(R.string.blabs));
                startActivity(blabby);
                return true; */
                //-------- Added for separate page

            case R.id.menu_pin:
                Intent pin = new Intent(Folders.this, Pinned_items.class);
                startActivity(pin);
                return true;
                //-------- Added for separate page

            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Intent settings = new Intent(Folders.this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(settings);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_ticket_search:
                Intent search = new Intent(Folders.this, Search.class);
                search.putExtra("set_queue", "no");
                startActivity(search);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    private class getbrand extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, JSONArray > {
        Dialog dialog;
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new Dialog(Folders.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String access = op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(), "ticket", "get_branding", "");
            JSONArray access_denied = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(access + "&vis_encode=json", Folders.this);
            return access_denied;

        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONArray access_denied) {
            super.onPostExecute(access_denied);
            String access_result = access_denied.toString();

            ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
            if (access_result.equals("[\"1\"]")) {
                ab.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                ab.setIcon(R.drawable.application_icon);
                //  ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
                //  ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
                //  ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));    
            } else {
                ab.setTitle(R.string.nobrand_app_name);
                ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
                ab.setIcon(R.drawable.white3);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folder_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#115c28"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folder_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#115c28"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/folder_display_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`

Comment: But where ...? I am new to android

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the question - I thought my answer would help but perhaps the question can be rewritten with images so that it can help others because I'm not sure what the adapter has to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i just chage the xml template as follows.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100"
            >
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <!--  -->
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folder_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="30dip"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:textColor="#115c28"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folder_count"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#115c28"  
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="30dip"
            android:paddingLeft="35dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
            <!--  -->
            </LinearLayout>   


            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/folder_display_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


            </LinearLayout>
```

Its working properly now.

Answer (score 7):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folder_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

The first textview takes up the full width of the horizontal LinearLayout so you can't see the second textview.

You can see the count by making the width of the textviews `wrap_content` but it probably won't match the design you're trying to achieve.

Comment: :: Itried android:layout_width="wrap_parent"   but just shows th count not the names

Comment: Is there any issue of the listview at thebottom in the xml files

Comment: yep, they're all set to match_parent which isn't going to work out well in a horizontal linearlayout.

Comment: Then wt should I have to do?

Comment: it would help if you had a sketch of what you want, and a sketch of what you have.

Comment: I just Want to displayl ike            New            0

Comment: New            0        Overdue           1      Trash            10             Spam             5             (One by one)

Comment: I cant upload the screen shot with the questions.

Comment: Upload to imgur and paste the link here - someone can then embed it into your question.